# Printing 2D Matrix in a given format

Tags: java, algorithm

//Given a number n i want to generate the corresponding 2-d matrix for it .
//for example for n = 1 my 2-D matrix should be

for n = 1

1 2
   3 4

for n = 2

```
1  2  5  6
3  4  7  8
9  10 13 14
11 12 15 16
```

for n = 3

```
1  2  5  6  17 18 21 22 
3  4  7  8  19 20 23 24 
9  10 13 14 25 26 29 30 
11 12 15 16 27 28 31 32 
33 34 37 38 49 50 53 54 
35 36 39 40 51 52 55 56 
41 42 45 46 57 58 61 62 
43 44 47 48 59 60 63 64
```

Comment: Cool. Go with it. Don't hesitate to ask once you have tried something and have an actual concrete question.

Comment: You should explain more to get help here, IFAIK, the max number is `4^n`, but I don't know how matrix structure based on `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be solved using recursion. For example, the code below prints exactly the required matrix for a given `n`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int n = scanner.nextInt();
        final int[][] matrix = create(1, (int) Math.pow(2, n));
        print(matrix);
    }

    private static int[][] create(final int startValue, final int size) {
        if (size == 1) {
            return new int[][]{{startValue}};
        } else {
            final int half = size / 2;
            final int step = half * half;
            return combine(create(startValue, half), create(startValue + step, half),
                    create(startValue + 2 * step, half), create(startValue + 3 * step, half));
        }
    }

    private static int[][] combine(final int[][] m1, final int[][] m2, final int[][] m3, final int[][] m4) {
        final int initialSize = m1.length;
        final int sizeOfResult = initialSize * 2;
        final int[][] result = new int[sizeOfResult][sizeOfResult];
        for (int row = 0; row < initialSize; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < initialSize; col++) {
                result[row][col] = m1[row][col];
                result[row][col + initialSize] = m2[row][col];
                result[row + initialSize][col] = m3[row][col];
                result[row + initialSize][col + initialSize] = m4[row][col];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void print(final int[][] matrix) {
        for (final int[] row : matrix) {
            for (final int val : row) {
                System.out.printf("%-5d", val);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```